# Redirecting file-URL to angular component

Tags: angular, router, angular4-router

Hello i want to migrate a existing link in my angular 4 project.
For example my link is "http://www.test.com/test/site.aspx".

I tried in my router configurations :

```
    path: 'test', 
    component: TestComponent,
    children: [{
      path: '',
      component: ContactComponent
    }]
```

and

```
        path: 'test/site.aspx', 
        component: ContactComponent
```

but none of this is working.
Any Idea how to solve this Problem ?

Comment: What's the error thrown?

Comment: {path: '**', redirectTo: '/404'} - at the end its routing to my 404 Page

Comment: Swap the paths, there is priority involved.

Comment: None of both is working. Even swapping does not change the result.

Answer (score -1):

Use redirectTo like below:

`{ path: 'test/site.aspx', redirectTo: '/contact', pathMatch: 'full' },
 { path: 'contact', component: ContactComponent},`

Comment: I throws "site not found" page / but "/contact" is working ... It seems somehow it try to gets to the file

Comment: Are you able to browse to contact component directly? what is the url you use to directly reach contact component?